# Model.SetViewName in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I know what is addObject here.
Can anyone please tell me what is **modelAndView.setViewName**("vendorInfo");

Sorry I am a Beginner

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listSupplier",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView supplierList() {
    List<Supplier> supplierList=adminService.listSuppliers();
    modelAndView.setViewName("vendorInfo");
    modelAndView.addObject("suppliersList", supplierList);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sets the name of the view to be resolved by the configured [`ViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html). So let's say your view is in `/WEB-INF/views/vendorInfo.jsp` and view resolver  is configured with prefix `/WEB-INF/views/` and suffix `.jsp`, then the view resolver will know to use the `prefix + viewName + suffix` as the view that will be rendered.

- [`ModelAndView` JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#setViewName-java.lang.String-)