# How can I change the view contents of modelandview in the spring controller part?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

How can I change the view contents of modelandview in the spring controller part???

i want put String Contents in view

maybe code like this

```
{ 
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView;

  mv.addObject("userid", userId);
  mv.setView("\<html>\<h1>#{userid}\</h1>\<html>");

  return mv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set view-name using ModelAndView.setViewName(String viewName) method.

You can refer to this answer: [Model.SetViewName in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320913/model-setviewname-in-spring)

Comment: thanks you for answer but i want put String not path

Comment: Why do you want to add some textual content as part of your view name. You can add it in your model instead. Please elaborate your requirement.